# Dimensional restrictions on the AdS/CFT correspondence?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, ads-cft

Since there are no bicontinuous bijections between Riemannian manifolds of different
dimensions, there cannot be any exact correspondences between wavefunctions on the bulk
and its boundary. How is this handled in AdS/CFT? Are wavefunctions defined only on a
discrete lattice? Is the correspondence one between the countable sets of Fourier coefficients of
$L_2$ functions on bounded domains?

Reply to Gold 2021-5-22:

I admit that I lack knowledge of the details of the proposed AdS/CFT correspondence, but I do
know enough to ask, I think, some fairly reasonable questions, which may be answerable just by
some clarification for me of what the correspondence is supposed to do.

One thing I think it is supposed to be good for is to solve difficult problems in quantum field
theory in N dim. space by transposing them to easier gravitational problems in N+1 dim. space
(is this about right?). The N dim. QFT problem, represented, e.g., by an N dim. wavefunction
$\Psi$, can be transferred to N+1 dim. space just by embedding $\Psi$ into that space.
However, we are then left with an N dim. wavefunction in N+1 dim. space, which is physically of
no significance. It must be done some other way. What way?

A problem more closely connected with my original objection is the, maybe just popular but
really not technically believed to be possible, problem of how to represent (at least
mathematically, using physical theory) our existence in the N+1 dim. bulk as an existence on the
N dim. boundary. Assuming that our existence in N+1 dim. space is represented by N+1 dim.
wavefunctions, exactly representing it in N dim. space requires somehow representing those
N+1 dim. wavefunctions in N dim. space. To be physically useful, this must be done in a
continuous manner. This requirement is similar to the requirement that for a physical initial
(boundary) value problem to be properly posed, its solution must be continuously dependent on
the initial (boundary) values, otherwise arbitrarily small errors in the initial (boundary) data could
result in errors in the solution bigger than some fixed value. The required continuous representation of N+1 dim. wavefunctions in N dim. space doesn't exist, therefore some approximation is required.
This limitation is well known in the holographic analogy. A hologram of a 3 dim. scene is a 2
dim. representation of that scene, but only an approximate one, whose resolution gets more and
more accurate as the wavelength of the light used to create it approaches zero, but never is
exact. This limitation is reflected in the fact that the claim that all of the information in the
hologram is contained in every small piece of it is inaccurate; the smaller the piece of the
hologram, the poorer the resolution of the resulting image.

Comment: I would say that this is a misunderstanding of how the ${\rm AdS}/{\rm CFT}$ correspondence works. It requires in no away a continuous bijection between points in the boundary and points in the bulk.

Comment: The answer to this misconception is that the number of degrees of freedom in a quantum gravity theory are much less than one expects! Also the mapping between boundary and bulk doesn’t need to be nice or simple.